# How do I Display Nagios Host Custom Variables or Macros in the Web Interface?

Tags: nagios

How can I display custom host variables in the Nagios web interface such as `_mac_address`?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the same question, and I don't want to use the notes directive

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using the `notes` directive inside of the host definition even if the variables are also defined their and they will show up in the host detail page (`extinfo.cgi`). For example:

```
define host {
        host_name web01
        display_name web01
        address 8.8.4.4
        _mac_address  00:21:9B:00:21:9B
        _sw_port_1    sw01_g3
        notes $_HOSTMAC_ADDRESS$ $_HOSTSW_PORT_1$
        hostgroups +webservers
        use web_servers
}
```

Comment: That is a great little tip. Thanks... 6 years later!